# Proof that Ext Sheaves $\mathscr{Ext}^i _{O_Y}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$ are Coherent

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

I have some questions about a proof given in my class (unfortunately I not found the original source) of following statement:

Let $Y$ a Noetherian scheme and $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ two ***coherent*** sheaves on $Y$ then $\mathscr{Ext}^i _{O_Y}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$ is also coherent for $i \ge 0$.

The PROOF works as follows:

The problem is in following way local: Since $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent locally for an appropriaty small open $U \subset Y$ there exist a free resolution

(*)$$... \to \mathcal{E}_1 \to \mathcal{E}_0 \to \mathcal{F} \vert _U \to 0 $$

where the $\mathcal{E}_j$ are ***free*** $O_U$ modules of ***finite rank*** (works since $\mathcal{F}$ coherent).

Since the Ext-sheaves bahave well under localizations there is an identity

$${Ext}^i _{O_Y}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}) \vert _U ={Ext}^i _{O_U}(\mathcal{F} \vert _U, \mathcal{G} \vert _U)$$

So we can assume $U=Y$ and $\mathcal{F} \vert _U=\mathcal{F} $ has free resolution from above.

Appling Hom to the exact free resolution (*) we obtain the the complex $\mathscr{Hom}_{O_Y}(\mathcal{E}_{\bullet}, \mathcal{G})$ of $O_Y$-modules.

Taking it's cohomology we obtain the sheaves $\mathscr{Ext}^i (\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$.

Now comes first inderstanding problem: the author of the proof wants to compare them with the functor "$i$-th comology functor" $\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$ of $\mathscr{Hom}_{O_Y}(\mathcal{E}_{\bullet}, \mathcal{G})$.

Local calculations show that $\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$ is a so called [$\delta$-functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-functor).

Making a comparison we conclude

$$ \mathscr{Ext}^i (\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})=\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$$

because:

The booth coinside in $i=$ since $\mathscr{Hom}(-, \mathcal{G})$ is left exact and both vanish for ***injective***  $\mathcal{G}$. Therefore both are ***Universal $δ$-functors*** (by Grothendieck's criterion for universal $\delta$-functors (Hartshorne's AG Theorem 1.3A, page 206). Since agin both coinside in $i=0$ and and are characterized by a universal property both sides must couside in all $i$.

But $\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$ is "obvious" (WHY?) coherent. Fini.

Following two questions:

1. Why is $\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$ is "obvious" ***coherent***?
2. Why do we need to make this tour around the theory of (universal) $\delta$-functors? Can we just observe that all $\mathscr{Hom}_{O_Y}(\mathcal{E}_{j}, \mathcal{G})$ are coherent and coclude directly that their cohomology is also coherent?

Or is the story a bit more difficult and I don't see the advantange of 
the delta functor $\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$?

Aren't  $\mathscr{Ext}^i (\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$ and 
$\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$ both the same by definition
of cohomology based on freeness of choice of projective resolution?
(free resolutions ***are*** projective.

From naive point of view for me the proof seems to work like:

"we want show that an object is coherent, we take this object, give it 
another name and then - after giving this new name to it -
it is ***obviously*** coherent.

Which detail I oversee?

Remark N# 1: Regarding the coherence of 
$\mathscr{Hom}_{O_Y}(\mathcal{E}_{j}, \mathcal{G})$.

I think that it is obvious since we are work locally!. so

1. $\mathcal{E}_{j}= \mathcal{O}_{Y}^n$
2. $\mathscr{Hom}_{O_Y}(\mathcal{O}_{Y}, \mathcal{G}) \cong \mathcal{G}$

Combining 1. and 2. we obtain $\mathscr{Hom}_{O_Y}(\mathcal{E}_{i}, \mathcal{G})\cong \mathcal{G}^n $
locally and coherence is a local property. Is the argument ok?

But if we know that $\mathscr{Hom}_{O_Y}(\mathcal{E}_{i}, \mathcal{G})$
are coherent  why it is obvious that $\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$ are
also coherent?

Remark N# 2: I know that there are maybe more ways to proof the statement
but the main point of this thread is to understand the logic behind this proof.

Comment: Note that the category of sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules does not have enough projective so $\operatorname{Ext}$ cannot be computed using a projective resolution of the first argument, and indeed, even if $\mathcal{O}_X$ is free, $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F})$ might be non zero. It works for the Ext-sheaves though, and a possible proof is going through the theory of $\delta$-functors.

Comment: @Roland: ah ok I think I understand it partially (please correct me otherwise):so $\mathscr{Ext}^i (\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$ cannot be just calculated by taking cohomology of $\mathscr{Hom}_{O_Y}(\mathcal{E}_{\bullet}, \mathcal{G})$ (***at first glance!***) since one cannot expect that the local free (so projective) resolution glues together to a projective one (since there maybe simply exist not enough projectives as you stated).

Comment: But instead you take $\mathscr{Ext}^i (\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$ as "abstract object" and show with this universality $\delta$-functor argument that they coincide with $\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$ which are ***defined*** as the cohomologies $\mathscr{Hom}_{O_Y}(\mathcal{E}_{\bullet}, \mathcal{G})$. So ***only after*** realizing that $\mathscr{Ext}^i (\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})=\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$ with $\delta$-functor theory arguments we can argue over free resolution since the right hand since is defined in this way. This is the philosphy,right?

Comment: Is this argumentation is so far correct, then the only problem is why $\mathcal{E}^i(\mathcal{G})$ is coherent?

Comment: Yes that is pretty much it. In fact, $\mathcal{O}_X$ is not projective, though it is free. My previous comment was not clear on that point. As your second question, the kernel and cokernel of a morphism of coherent sheaves are coherent. It follows easily that the cohomology sheaves of a complex of coherent sheaves are coherent.

Comment: @Roland:
hmmm, but the statement that "kernel and cokernel of a morphism of coherent sheaves are coherent" is only true if $X$ is locally Noetherian,right? Or does it hold over arbitrary scheme? (in our case it's true, but I was curious how general it is). Since every submodule of Noetherian module is Noetherian, so finitely generated, we are done.

Comment: I believe it is true for any scheme but I am not certain as I mostly works with noetherian ones. You should check in ega or in the stack project.

Comment: @Roland: Yes, indeed it's true in general case: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05CU. Thank you again for explanations.